# How to view the SWT examples (Eclipse) source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I just downloaded the SWT examples from the Eclipse site but I have a problem: I cannot view the source code. I can launch the Control Example application (which I need) but if I create a project with those .jar-s included I just see empty packages in them. What do I do wrong? Is there a way to see those .java files?

I'm developing an RCP application for Eclipse and those examples can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I zipped out the .jar-s on my filesystem and now I see the sources. :)

So if someone runs into this problem, then you just have to unzip the .jar-s located in the plugins directory.

Answer (score 4):

Download the archive with examples from eclipse download site (e.g. [org.eclipse.sdk.examples-3.7.zip](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/download.php?dropFile=org.eclipse.sdk.examples-3.7.zip)).

Locate the `plugins\org.eclipse.swt.examples.source_3.7.0.v3735b.jar` (or other appropriate jar version) file in the archive and extract the content (*jar are just renamed zip files*) to some existing Eclipse project or create new one (e.g. SWTExamples). In the `src` folder you can find all example's sources. To run control example, run project with main class `org.eclipse.swt.examples.controlexample.ControlExample`.

In the package `org.eclipse.swt.examples.controlexample` you can find sources for which are you looking for.

IMHO the control examples have quite complicated source code, but there could be found what you need.

Answer (score 2):

As listed on the SWT examples page:

If you have downloaded them and run them inside Eclipse, the sources can be found in `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.examples.[exampleName].source_[version].jar`

If you downloaded the .jar's directly, you have instructions on the examples page (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php) on how to install them in eclipse, which should download the source .jar's.

Comment: I already did this. If I reference those .jar-s and look into them I just see empty packages. I figured out that .jar-s postfixed with _source should contain the source code but they did not...or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I downloaded the jars from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.2-201102101200/org.eclipse.sdk.examples-3.6.2.zip and could find the source files in the _source jars. How are you opening the .jar files? Have you tried extracting them?